# iTunesToRhythm code not working?

Tags: command-line

Hello I am trying to install run this [iTunesToRhythm](https://github.com/esalgado/iTunesToRhythm).

The supplied command is:

```
iTunesToRhythm.py -w -a iTunes\ Music\ Library.xml ~/.local/share/rhythmbox/rhythmdb.xml
```

The error I am getting after inputting this command is:

```
iTunesToRhythm.py: command not found
```

EDIT - here is what I typed in console:

```
fiver@LALA-LAND:~/Music/iTunesToRhythm-master$ ./iTunesToRhythm.py -w -a /media/MEDIA 1/SOUNDS/I Tunes/lybrary.xml ~/.local/share/rhythmbox/rhythmdb.xml
```

Comment: The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the *edit* button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `./` (current dir) prefix when you execute a script:

```
cd /home/myname/Music/iTunesToRhythm-master/
./iTunesToRhythm.py -w -a /media/MEDIA\ 1/SOUNDS/I\ Tunes/Library.xml ~/.local/share/rhythmbox/rhythmdb.xml
```

or

```
./iTunesToRhythm.py -w -a "/media/MEDIA 1/SOUNDS/I Tunes/Library.xml" ~/.local/share/rhythmbox/rhythmdb.xml
```

The reason is that current dir is not included to `$PATH` variable, because it may cause security risks. Somebody can override system commands this way.

There is [question on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/156582/why-is-not-in-the-path-by-default) which explains why.

Also you should *escape* space bars inside filenames with backslash `\` symbol. Simply place it before spaces. Or use double-quotes `"` around the path.

Comment: thank you could you explain what this is doing? i cant execute the command properly the dir is wrong or something, maybe i can move stuff manually

Comment: i am trying ./home/myname/Music/iTunesToRhythm-master/iTunesToRhythm.py -w -a home/myname/Music/ library.xml ~/.local/share/rhythmbox/rhythmdb.xml is this not wokring becuase the slashes are facing the wrong way or ? i really am new to this

Comment: Are you running a script from the directory it is placed? Otherwise you should use full path.

Comment: just edited my above comment.. also here is what I am trying to do 

https://github.com/esalgado/iTunesToRhythm

Comment: i ran it from the home and from the folder the script is located in.

Comment: You have mistakenly placed `.` before `/` which means to system that you want to use relevant path instead of absolute path to file. It looks probably for `/home/myname/home/myname/Music/iTunesToRhythm-master/iTunesToRhythm.py`

Comment: YOu are such a graet help, however i am still messing it up./ There has been spome progress though., Now the error i am getting is: Reading input from iTunes Music Library.xml
 Unable to open file. File not found

Comment: Did you place that file inside `/home/myname/Music/iTunesToRhythm-master/` folder? Is the iTunes library called that?

Comment: the XML file? no. but the path of the py file is:
/home/fiver/Music/iTunesToRhythm-master/TunesToRhythm.py

Comment: and what's the path for iTunes library?

Comment: iTunesToRhythm.py: error: you must supply a source and destination

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/436770/itunestorhythm-errors

Answer (score 1):

When I run Python scripts, I put `python` in front of the script I want to run. Kind of like putting `sh` before the name of a shell script you want to run.

For example, go to the directory where your `.py` script is in the command line and run it directly from there or include the path:

```
python iTunesToRhythm.py -w -a iTunes\ Music\ Library.xml ~/.local/share/rhythmbox/rhythmdb.xml
```

or:

```
python ~/Downloads/iTunesToRhythm.py -w -a ~/iTunes\ Music\ Library.xml ~/.local/share/rhythmbox/rhythmdb.xml
```

But I'm pretty sure the command you were missing was 'python'.